# Cant figure out the testcase where I am getting segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, stack

I am getting segmentation fault for some unknown test case and I am unable to resolve it.
It runs for most of the cases. I only want to know in which case I am getting segmentation fault.
The code is written for the Question Maximim Rectangular Area in a Histogram. You can check this question here: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-rectangular-area-in-a-histogram-1587115620/1#

Below is the code:

```
 long long getMaxArea(long long arr[], int n)
    {
        int nsl[n];
        int nsr[n];
        stack<int>s;
        // nsl
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                nsl[i]=-1;
                s.push(i);
            }
            else{
                while(!s.empty())
                {
                    if(arr[s.top()]<arr[i])
                    break;
                    s.pop();
                }
                if(s.empty())
                nsl[i]=-1;
                else
                nsl[i]=s.top();
                s.push(i);
            }
        }
        stack<int>st;
        // nsr
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(i==n-1)
            {
                nsr[i]=n;
                st.push(i);
            }
            else{
                while(!st.empty())
                {
                    if(arr[st.top()]<arr[i])
                    break;
                    st.pop();
                }
                if(st.empty())
                nsr[i]=n;
                else
                nsr[i]=st.top();
                st.push(i);
            }
        }
        long long ans=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        ans=max(ans,arr[i]*(nsr[i]-nsl[i]-1));
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Note that `int nsl[n];` is not valid C++

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays.

Comment: This is one many reasons code golf sites are garbage for learning. How can you be expected to correct your code when you aren't given the inputs that cause it to fail?

Comment: @sweenish I think you mean code challenges, not code golf.

Comment: @Barmar It's the same difference.

Comment: `int nsl[n];` -- If `n` is large enough, you have exhausted the stack memory.  Don't do this, it isn't valid C++ anyway.  Use `std::vector<int> nsl(n), nsr(n);`.  Also, that website you linked to contains awful code examples for C++.  Whoa be it to the person going to that site and are using Visual C++.  They have to translate the bad, invalid C++ syntax being used into valid syntax so that it becomes compilable.

Comment: **1 ≤ N ≤ 10^6** and `int nsl[n]` eats somewhere above 2 MB of automatic storage and probably 4 to 8 MB. Typically systems provide between 1 and 10 MB Automatic storage. One of these array could be fatal, but 3 or 4 probably is fatal.

Comment: @user4581301 -- If using `std::vector` fixes the entire issue, this question should be archived and be the prime example as to why those sites are garbage coding sites.

Comment: Thanks the problem got solved by using vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by using vector instead of array. I was just using bad c++ syntax for array and hence using vector just solved it.